# mongoose: how to search mongoDB with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am learning Express.js, MongoDB and Mongoose, and i am creating a small app that lets me store items to a list.
I am trying to Create a GET /list/search route which allows to search for items in the list, but i haven't gotten it to work.
Here is my code

**Routes**

```
const express = require('express');

router = express.Router();

const db = require("../models");

router.get('/', function(req, res, next){
    db.List.find().then(function(list){
        res.render('index', {list});
    });
});

router.get('/new', function(req, res, next){
    res.render('new');
});

router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next){
    db.List.findById(req.params.id).then(function(list){
        res.render('show', {list});
    });
});

router.get('/:id/edit', function(req, res, next){
    db.List.findById(req.params.id).then(function(list){
        res.render('edit', {list});
    });
});

router.get('/search', function(req, res, next){
    db.List.findOne(req.query.search).then(function(list){
        console.log(list);
        res.render('show', {list});
    });
});

router.post('/', function(req, res, next){
    db.List.create(req.body).then(function(list){
        res.redirect('/');
    });
});

router.patch('/:id', function(req, res, next){
    db.List.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body).then(function(list){
        res.redirect('/');
    });
});

router.delete('/:id', function(req, res, next){
    db.List.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id).then(function(list){
        res.redirect('/');
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**Index.pug**
extends base.pug

```
block content
h1 My List
form(action="/list/search" method="GET")
    input(type="text" name="search")
    input(type="submit", value="search")
a(href="/list/new") Add New Item!
each item in list
    p ITEM: #{item.name}   QUANTITY: #{item.quantity}&nbsp;
            a(href=`/list/${item.id}/edit`) Edit
```

my main problem is the  **GET /search**, i want to pass in a search query to the search box and return the result to the render file

```
router.get('/search', function(req, res, next){
        db.List.findOne(req.query.search).then(function(list){
            console.log(list);
            res.render('show', {list});
        });
    });
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the parameters [as attributes in the query](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html). `list` will be `null`, if no matching record was found.

```
router.get('/search', function (req, res, next) {
  db.List.findOne({
    name: req.query.name,
    age: req.query.age
  }).then(function (list) {
    console.log(list);
    if (list === null) {
      return res.render('show', {
        list: []
      });
    }
    return res.render('show', {
      list: list
    });
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log('err', err);
    return res.render('show', {
      list: []
    });
  });
});
```